# Is there a way to open the external page for oauth within the PWA, without opening the browser and still maintain manifest file?

Tags: oauth, progressive-web-apps

I have researched on it for a while and still there's no solution which doesn't include deleting manifest file

Comment: Can you include in your question your findings and your sources?